# Both active and reactive UVM agent

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm developing a UVM agent for a protocol which has both rx and tx transactions on same signals.

How do I implement this?

I thought about a driver which will get items from 2 different sequencers, one for RX (reactive) and second for TX (active).
But from researching the web it seems incorrect.

I would like to hear what is the right way to do this in UVM.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology may be different from what the UVM uses. The UVM has ACTIVE and INACTIVE agents where an INACTIVE agent is simply one that never drives a bus.

What you want is sometimes called a *slave sequence*, or a *responder*.

A slave sequence sends a dummy request sequence_item to the driver, in your case the RX driver, and waits for a transaction from the TX driver. The RX driver sends a response back to the slave_sequence, and the next sequence item is actually a response to the previous sequence_item.

So the meaning of request and response gets reversed in a slave_sequence, and shifted into the next sequence_item. You can find examples [here](https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/sequences/slave) and [here](https://www.verilab.com/files/mastering_reactive_slaves.pdf).

Comment: So I need 2 different drivers?
In the same agent?

Comment: You will need two different drivers. Whether they are In the same agent or not depends on how they are related to each other.